# FHIR read/write rules on determinated resource field

Tags: hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I want to know if is it possible define in `FHIR` a strategy about read / write specific resource field.

i.e. I have a `ServiceRequest` resource.

I want to grant for a specific profile / role write on `authoredOn` field and I want to prevent the write for another profile / role.

I try to read `CapabilitySystem` resource but I think it don't fit my aim.

In FHIR, in which part of it, I can define profiles and roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, updates are to the whole resource, not to individual fields.  You're free to define business rules that reject an update on the grounds that a field has changed that a user isn't authorized to manipulate, but there's no standard way to express this limitation in the CapabilityStatement.  (You could define an extension though.)